# Javascript is not working in rails 2.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I did a jquery to block the search button until my textfields has text but is not working.

When I write values into textfields the search button is still block and not unblock like this:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/qKG5F/1627/
```

Here is the controller:

```
class PolicyController < ApplicationController
   def index
     @policies = Policy.find(:all,:conditions=>['date BETWEEN ? AND ?',params[cam],params[:cam2] ])
   end
end
```

Here is the view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
  $('form > input').keyup(function() {

    var empty = false;
    $('form > input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
    });

    if (empty) {
        $('#search').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('#search').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
})()
</script>

<% form_tag :controller=>"policy",:action=>"index" do %>
   From: <%= calendar_date_select_tag  "date1", params[:date1]  %>

   To:   <%= calendar_date_select_tag  "date2",params[:date2] %>   
   <input type="submit" id="search" value="GO" />
<% end %>

<% @policies.each  do |p|%>
   <%= p.date_ini %>
<% end %>
```

I tried:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

And also I have the prototype 1.6.0.3 file in /public/javascripts/prototype.js

Also I don't have any errors in log

Somebody told me about convert jquery code to prototype code.

Please somebody can help me with this?

Comment: What does the javascript console on the browser say? Any errors?

Comment: No errors in logs Processing PolicyController#index (for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-14 23:26:06) [GET]

Comment: Everything seems working without problems.Maybe i need something else?

Comment: Your issue doesn't seem to be Rails-related, but somehow Javascript-related. Please take a look at the Javascript console log in your browser, not in the RoR logs on the server. And lets try to pinpoint and find out where/what it is.

Comment: Marco i pressed f12 and clicked on console and didn't see anything wrong. What could be the problem?

Comment: Well seems that you are right, i have prototype, application , autonumeric and effects.js and seems that is not working for them is there any way to hide all javascript files and use <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>

Comment: Do you have `application.js` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include the `Prototype` and `Scriptaculous` javascript libraries in your application, pass `:defaults` as the source. When using `:defaults`, if an `application.js` file exists in your public javascripts directory, it will be included as well.

```
  javascript_include_tag :defaults # =>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/effects.js"></script>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/application.js"></script>
```

If you have issues with `:defaults` reference,

Try to use `:all` option.

```
javascript_include_tag :all # =>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/effects.js"></script>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/application.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/shop.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/checkout.js"></script>
```

Refer: http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.2/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/javascript_include_tag

OR explicitly refer the `prototype.js` file,

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "prototype" %>
```

Hope it helps :)